# Index Match with Match Ranges

Tags: excel-formula, index-match

I am attempting an Index-Match in which the match array consists of two criteria: it is greater than one column but less than or equal to a second column.

Simplified example:
[Match-Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUK0B.png)

=INDEX(C29,MATCH(A29,(A29>D29)*(A29<=E29),0))

This results in an error.

Comment: why index match? you are only comparing 1 to 1 not 1 to many?  a simple IF will do this:  `=IF(AND(A29>D29,A29<=E29),C29,"")`

Comment: Instead of a 1-to-1, in the complete example, Column C, D, and E. Will consist of 20+ rows, resulting in many possible ranges in which the lookup value could fall. This is a simplified example with only one row

Comment: your example should show that it is at least multiple rows or we will get the wrong idea of what you are trying: `=INDEX(C$29:C$49,MATCH(1,(A29>D$29:D$49)*(A29<=E$29:E$49),0))` the lookup range will return an array on 1s and 0s.  You need to search for the first 1 not the value in A29.  Also depending on your version you may need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.